Adjoint operator to a discrete gradient
For PDHG implementation I am trying to implement discrete gradient and its adjoint operator. Some sources say that divergence is adjoint to the gradient, however from the matrix perspective, I think the following two shall be adjoint
void kernel FLOATvector_2DisotropicGradient(global const float* restrict F,
                                            global float* restrict GX,
                                            global float* restrict GY,
                                            private int3 vdims,
                                            private float3 voxelSizes)
{
    const int i = get_global_id(0);
    const int j = get_global_id(1);
    const int k = get_global_id(2);
    const int IND = VOXELINDEX(i, j, k, vdims);
    float v = F[IND];
    float3 grad;
    if(i + 1 == vdims.x)
    {    
        grad.x = -v;
    } else 
    {    
        grad.x = F[IND + 1] - v; 
    }    
    if(j + 1 == vdims.y)
    {    
        grad.y = -v;
    } else 
    {    
        grad.y = F[IND + vdims.x] - v; 
    }    
    grad /= voxelSizes;
    GX[IND] = grad.x;
    GY[IND] = grad.y;
}
void kernel FLOATvector_isotropicBackDivergence2D(global const float* restrict FX,
                                                  global const float* restrict FY,
                                                  global float* restrict DIV, 
                                                  private int3 vdims,
                                                  private float3 voxelSizes)
{
    const int i = get_global_id(0);
    const int j = get_global_id(1);
    const int k = get_global_id(2);
    const int IND = VOXELINDEX(i, j, k, vdims);
    float VX = FX[IND];
    float VY = FY[IND];
    float DX, DY;
    if(i == 0)
    {    
        // out = 0.0f;
        DX = -VX; 
    } else 
    {    
        DX = FX[IND - 1] - VX;
    }    
    if(j == 0)
    {    
        //        out = 0.0f;
        DY = -VY; 
    } else 
    {    
        DY = FY[IND - vdims.x] - VY;
    }    
    DX = DX / voxelSizes.x;
    DY = DY / voxelSizes.y;
    DIV[IND] = DX + DY;
    // Actually works better
    // DIV[IND] = -DX - DY;
}

With  DIV[IND] = -DX - DY; the implementation works better. Indeed my implementation of divergence computes minus divergence but from the perspective of matrix transpose, I feel minus divergence is proper adjoint operator to gradient. What do I miss here?
